# Shopify get published or unpublished state from Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Is there a method in Liquid that can tell me if a theme is the store's live theme or if it's unpublished?

I am wondering is something like `{{ theme.role }}` is possible (I know that this particular one was deprecated) and then I would get `published` or `unpublished` in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ theme.role }}` - it's available for now, but not documented as far as I see. It returns:

- main - for published theme
- unpublished